# Python div class extract content

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a text between the strings `"<div><p class='entete_propriete'>DNA sequence </p>"` and `"</div>"`:

```
    handle = open(i, 'r')
    name = i.split('=')[1]
    print name
    soup = BeautifulSoup(handle,"lxml")
    for item in soup:
        seq = soup.findAll(seq) 
        print seq

    <section>
    <div><p class='entete_propriete' align='center'>Ends</p>
<br><span class='entete_propriete'>IR Length : </span>44/49<br><br><span class='entete_propriete_bis'>IRL : </span><span class='seq'>GAGGGTCGGCAGGGATTCGTGTAAAACACAGCCAAAAGTGAGCTAACTCC</span><br><span class='entete_propriete_bis'>IRR : </span><span class='seq'>GAGGGTCGACAGGGATTTGTGTAAAAAACAGCCAAAATTGAGCTAAATCT</span><br>   </div>
    <div><p class='entete_propriete' align='center'>Insertion site</p><br>
<table><tr><th>Left flank</th><th>Direct repeat</th><th>Right flank</th><th>DR Length</th></tr><tr> <td class='seq' align='right'>TCCACTACCT</td><td class='seq' align='center'></td><td class='seq' align='left'>TCGTTGAGCA</td><td class='seq' align='center'>0</td></tr></table> </div>
    <div class="piedSection"></div>       
    </section>
        <section>
    <div id=seq_ident><p>IS1007</p><ul><li><span class='entete_propriete'>Family </span>IS6</li><li><span class='entete_propriete'>Group </span></li></ul></div><span class='entete_propriete'> MGE type </span>IS<span class='entete_propriete_decal'>Related element(s) : </span><br><span class='entete_propriete'>Isoform </span><span class='entete_propriete_decal'>Synonym(s) </span>    <div class="piedSection"></div>
        </section>
            <div><p class='entete_propriete'>DNA sequence </p>
    <div class='seq'>GGCACTGTTGCAAATAGGCTGACATGATAAGCTAAATATCTTATTTATTTCGAGATACAGCAGATGAATCCCTTCCACGGTCGGCACTTTCAAGGTGAAA<br />
GAGAAGTTTGGCTAGTAAATAGAGTTTTCGGTCTCTAAGCTTTTTTGAAGGGAAAATCATTGACTCAGAT<br />
CCCTATTTGCAACAGTGCC </div>
```

And the output is this:

```
IS1007
[]
[]
```

If I can get this I can remove the {`\<\br/>`} after.

```
TATCTTATTTATTTCGAGATACAGCAGATGAATCCCTTCCACGGTCGGCACTTTCAAGGTGAAA<br />
GAGAAGTTTGGCTAGTAAATAGAGTTTTCGGTCTCTAAGCTTTTTTGAAGGGAAAATCACTCAG<br />
ATCCCTATTTGCAACAGTGCC </div>
```

Any suggestion to extract the sequence contained between:

```
\<\div\>\<\p class='entete_propriete'>DNA sequence \<\/\p\>
    <div class='seq'>
```

and

```
\<\div\>
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Any suggestion to extract the text that I mentioned before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_text()` method or `text` attributes to get the data from tags

```
for item in soup:
   seq = soup.findAll(seq) 
   print seq.get_text()
```

you can also use `seq.text`